# An enigma style simulation machine in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, enigma-machine

This code made a few breaks back in my spare time. There are, however, a few alterations to the original machine that this simulation shows, one being the alphabet, another being the amount of rotors.

```
from random import *
import msvcrt
import os
from os import walk
english = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',',','.','?','-','+','=','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',' ','\'','"','!']
def diskgen(alphabet):
    #DISK GENERATION
    disk_avail = []
    disk_direc = []
    disk_map = []
    for num in range (0,len(alphabet)):
        disk_avail.append(num)
        disk_direc.append(num)
    #Begin mapping
    while len(disk_direc) > 0:
        choose_ep = randint(0,len(disk_avail)-1)
        exit_position = disk_avail[choose_ep]
        disk_map.append(exit_position)
        del disk_avail[choose_ep]
        del disk_direc[0]
    for pos in range (0,len(alphabet)):
        disk_map[pos] = disk_map[pos] - pos
    return disk_map
def reflector(alphabet):
    reflect_avail = []
    reflect_map = []
    for num in range (0,len(alphabet)):
        reflect_avail.append(num)
        reflect_map.append('x')
    if len(reflect_avail)%2 == 0:
        while len(reflect_avail) > 0:
            from_num = reflect_avail[0]
            to_pos = randint(1,len(reflect_avail)-1)
            fin_num = reflect_avail[to_pos]
            reflect_map[from_num] = fin_num
            reflect_map[fin_num] = from_num
            del reflect_avail[0]
            del reflect_avail[to_pos-1]
        for pos in range (0,len(alphabet)):
            reflect_map[pos] = reflect_map[pos] - pos
        return reflect_map
def rotate(selected_disk):
    new_disk = []
    new_disk.append(selected_disk[len(selected_disk)-1])
    for pos in range (0,len(selected_disk)-1):
        new_disk.append(selected_disk[pos])
    return new_disk

def code(reflector,letter,language,disk1,disk2,disk3,disk4):
    language_map = {}
    for x in range (0,len(language)):
        language_map.update({language[x]:x})
    ltnumb = language_map[letter]
    disk1_scramble = (disk1[ltnumb] + ltnumb + len(disk1))%len(disk1)
    disk2_scramble = (disk2[disk1_scramble] + disk1_scramble + len(disk2))%len(disk2)
    disk3_scramble = (disk3[disk2_scramble] + disk2_scramble + len(disk3))%len(disk3)
    disk4_scramble = (disk4[disk3_scramble] + disk3_scramble + len(disk4))%len(disk4)
    rfb = (reflector[disk4_scramble] + disk4_scramble + len(reflector))%len(reflector)
    for x in range (0,len(disk4)):
        if (disk4[x]+x+len(disk4))%len(disk4) == rfb:
            disk4_reverse = x
            break
    for x in range (0,len(disk3)):
        if (disk3[x]+x+len(disk3))%len(disk3) == disk4_reverse:
            disk3_reverse = x
            break
    for x in range (0,len(disk2)):
        if (disk2[x]+x+len(disk2))%len(disk2) == disk3_reverse:
            disk2_reverse = x
            break
    for x in range (0,len(disk1)):
        if (disk1[x]+x+len(disk1))%len(disk1) == disk2_reverse:
            eletter = language[x]
            break
    return eletter

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)
if not os.path.exists(cwd+'\\rotor'):
    os.mkdir(cwd+'\\rotor')
f = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(cwd+'\\rotor'):
    f.extend(filenames)
files = []
for fname in f:
    if fname.endswith('.rotor'):
        files.append(fname.replace('.rotor',''))
start_selection = input('[1]\tNew Setting\n[2]\tReload Setting from file\n')
if start_selection == '2':
    print(files)
    for num in range (len(files)):
        print('['+str(num)+']\t'+files[num])
    f_choose = int(input())
    with open (cwd+'\\rotor\\'+files[f_choose]+'.rotor','r') as f:
        information = eval(f.read())
elif start_selection == '1':
    d1 = diskgen(english)
    d2 = diskgen(english)
    d3 = diskgen(english)
    d4 = diskgen(english)
    rf = reflector(english)
    d1rc = 0
    d2rc = 0
    d3rc = 0
    d4rc = 0
    rfrc = 0
    raw_type = ''
    enc_type = ''
    information = [d1,d2,d3,d4,rf,d1rc,d2rc,d3rc,d4rc,rfrc,raw_type,enc_type]
    wtf = input('Write to file? [y/n]: ')
    if (wtf == 'y') or (wtf == 'Y'):
        while True:
            name = input('NAME: ')
            os.system('cls')
            if not os.path.isfile(cwd+'\\rotor\\'+name+'.rotor'):
                newf = open(cwd+'\\rotor\\'+name+'.rotor','w')
                break
            if os.path.isfile(cwd+'\\rotor\\'+name+'.rotor'):
                proceed = input('File already exists, overwrite?\n[1]\tYes\n[2]\tNo\n')
                if proceed == '1':
                    newf = open(cwd+'\\rotor\\'+name+'.rotor','w')
                    break
        newf.write(str(information))
        newf.close()
os.system('cls')
d1 = information[0]
d2 = information[1]
d3 = information[2]
d4 = information[3]
rf = information[4]
d1rc = information[5]
d2rc = information[6]
d3rc = information[7]
d4rc = information[8]
rfrc = information[9]
raw_type = input('Plaintext: ')
enc_type = information[11]
word_address = 0
while word_address < len(raw_type):
    print(raw_type+'\n'+enc_type)
    letter = raw_type[word_address]
    os.system('cls')
    try:
        encoded_letter = code(rf,letter,english,d1,d2,d3,d4)
        enc_type += encoded_letter
    except:
        continue
    decoded_letter = code(rf,encoded_letter,english,d1,d2,d3,d4)
    d1 = rotate(d1)
    d1rc += 1
    if d1rc == len(d1):
        d1rc = 0
        d2 = rotate(d2)
        d2rc += 1
        if d2rc == len(d2):
            d2rc = 0
            d3 = rotate(d3)
            d3rc += 1
            if d3rc == len(d3):
                d4 = rotate(d4)
                d3rc = 0
                d4rc += 1
                if d4rc == len(d4):
                    d4rc = 0
                    rf = rotate(rf)
                    rfrc += 1
    word_address += 1
print(raw_type+'\n'+enc_type)
input()
```

If you happen to run this you'd find this to be slow (please run in console, not shell). It has the ability to generate valid disks and rotors if you need it, or save a rotor setting to a file.

There is just one hunch (apart from lazy coding at parts), which is that the displaying of the code text is slow. As you can see, it uses repeated `print`s and `cls`.

To make the code cross platform, I can use something like:

```
import os
def cls():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
cls()
```

I would like tips to give me better direction in how to better do this. Are there any obvious flaws that I have missed in all my testing?

I realise that this is not a good cryptographic tool in today's day and age. This is supposed to be more educational.

In which ways can this be better optimised and in which ways can I stamp out not obvious errors in the code?

Comment: (somewhat) related (codegolf though) https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71467/implement-the-enigma-machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some things related to performance and the code quality in general:

- what the `diskgen()` and `reflector()` functions do, does not really depend on the user's input and can be pre-computed to avoid wasting time during the runtime. Create the disk and reflector maps beforehand.
- to multiply the disk mappings, use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) instead of regenerating the mapping
- the rotation code can be improved by using slicing - might also be faster:

  ```
  def rotate(disk):
      return [disk[-1]] + disk[:-1]
  ```
- note the use of negative indexing and list slicing (you can apply these things in other parts of the code - it would not only make the code more concise and readable, but may provide performance boosts)
- you can make use of [`*args` and `**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) to pass around multiple arguments
- make use of [unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531776/multiple-unpacking-assignment-in-python-when-you-dont-know-the-sequence-length), e.g. you can improve the way you parse the `information` list (splited to multiple slices for readability):

  ```
  d1, d2, d3, d4 = information[:4]
  rf = information[4]
  d1rc, d2rc, d3rc, d4rc = information[5:9]
  rfrc = information[9]
  ```
- use [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [dictionary comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python)
- put the main program logic to under the [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)
- extract the user input part into a separate function
- the `english` list can be defined as a concatenation of sets of characters available in the `string` module:

  ```
  In [1]: import string

  In [2]: string.ascii_letters
  Out[2]: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  ```

Code organization-wise, the code really asks for a class ([of course, you don't have to write classes](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3717715)), say, `Machine` in which, the constructor method will be responsible for initializing disks and reflectors, the disks would be instance variables - you would simply access them via `self.diskN` instead of passing around from method to method. The rotation logic at the end of the program should also be extracted and be a part of this class.